# Select Linq-to-XML from Linq-to-Entities?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-xml

In mixing Linq-to-SQL and Linq-to-XML, I used to be able to do something like this:

```
XElement xml = new XElement("People");

xml.Add(from p in Context.People
        select new XElement("Person",
            new XElement("Id", p.Id),
            new XElement("Name", p.Name)));
```

In converting some stuff to EF, I now get this exception: "Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities."

This leads me to believe I now need to do something like this:

```
XElement xml = new XElement("People");

var peopleResults = Context.People.Select(p => { p.Id, p.Name }).ToList();

xml.Add(from p in peopleResults
        select new XElement("Person",
            new XElement("Id", p.Id),
            new XElement("Name", p.Name)));
```

Is this my only alternative now, or is there another cleaner way to express this in code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The approach is correct.  To shorten it slightly you can use the ToList method on the object directly.

```
XElement xml = new XElement("People");

xml.Add(from p in Context.People.ToList()
        select new XElement("Person",
            new XElement("Id", p.Id),
            new XElement("Name", p.Name)));
```

Comment: Creating a list of the rows in the table would be overkill here since the list is never really used beyond the enumeration.

Comment: @JeffMercado Correct.  ToList is overkill in this case, since the query is being consumed within the Add and there is no need to consider deference.

Answer (score 6):

Use LINQ to Objects when you do the projection.  To do that, just call `AsEnumerable()` beforehand.

```
XElement xml = new XElement("People");

xml.Add(from p in peopleResults.AsEnumerable()
        select new XElement("Person",
            new XElement("Id", p.Id),
            new XElement("Name", p.Name)));
```